# How to programmatically check the "Send copies of group conversations and events to group members" option for a group?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Using the Microsoft Graph API from an application scope (i.e. not delegated user scope) to successfully create Office 365 groups, I found no way to programatically set this option/checkbox which is available in the Microsoft Office 365 Admin Center GUI:

> "Send copies of group conversations and events to group members"

or in German:

> "Kopien von Gruppenunterhaltungen und Ereignissen an Gruppenmitglieder senden"

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) also gave me no hint.

My goal is to set this option so that emails being sent to this group are automatically forwarded to all members of this group.

#### My question

How to programatically set the "Send copies of group conversations and events to group members" option for a group from an Application scope?

#### Update 2022-09-16

Seems that the option now reads:

> "Send copies of team emails and events to team members' inboxes"

Comment: You can use the [autoSubscribeNewMembers property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) by making it to true. But make sure you first create the Group and later update the group with the autoSubscribeNewMembers property using PATCH as said in the document and later add the members.

Comment: Thanks, @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, it seems this is only possible when in delegated user scope, not in application scope. Because when doing it, I get an error `Code: ErrorGroupsAccessDenied, Message: User does not have permissions to execute this action`. (The group was created successfully right before).

Comment: Yeah I was also able to reproduce your issue. After a deep research I found that its a known issue on the Microsoft Graph. This property `autoSubscribeNewMembers` is supported for updating only through delegated permissions. Please read this [Note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) at the end of request body.

Comment: Thanks again, @Shiva-MSFTIdentity. Is there any chance that this will ever by enhanced/upgraded to work with application scope, too? Or any chance to somewhere suggest this as a feature somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we need to use the `autoSubscribeNewMembers` property for your requirement. But you can only use this property to update to group using Delegated permissions only. You cannot use Application permissions as its not supported as of now according to this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body).

There is also a uservoice which is already been created. Please go [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37573141-enable-updates-to-autosubscribenewmembers-when-u) and upvote this feature so that the Product team may implement it in the future.

Comment: Here is [a short PowerShell snippet](https://bonguides.com/microsoft-365-group-members-not-receive-emails-sent-to-group/) that configures all group members to receive messages that are sent to a Microsoft 365 group, even when they were already members _before_ setting the `autoSubscribeNewMembers` option.